# How to get js code to work in wordpress? It seems that wordpress ignores my script tags

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I tried to put this code to my wordpress site using custom html addon. The code can be seen in source code of the page so it is not deleted by wordpress. The code works fine on a normal html page but in wordpress it won't work. There is also normal html code in the same addon that works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.innerHTML = "Send";
btn.onclick = function() {
var nimi_ = document.getElementById("nimi").value;
var paikka_ = document.getElementById("paikka").value;
var muuta_ = document.getElementById("muuta").value;
window.open(`sms://12345678/?body=${nimi_ + paikka_ + muuta_ }`, "_blank");
};
document.body.appendChild(btn);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the browser's console for error messages? Can you link us to your wordpress site?

Comment: There isn't any errors in the console either. The code works fine in normal html page but somehow in wordpress it won't work even though i can see it in source code

Comment: You are just reiterating the information that's already in your question. If you won't link us to the website, we cannot debug this, since the code you show works in theory.